# Is there any way that can EXTEND (not mirror) my phone screen to another phone? Half-Half

Tags: screen, external-display

Just want a bigger display for my phone. I need to know how I can EXTEND my phone's screen to another phone, by using Bluetooth or WiFi or RF or web?

Few apps (iDisplay, AirScreen, AirDuet screen, etc) exist for only mirroring/sharing the screen - but not extending it. It's like using two monitors for your PC side-by-side & you select 'Extend display' between two monitors and hence the display bisects into two monitors. Same principle to phones.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried it (yet), but [DisplayLink Presenter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.displaylink.presenter) app might help, if you have the "dongle".

Comment: DisplayLink Presenter also just mirrors the Android phone screen, with usb hubs that have DisplayLink built in. Just tried it with both my Android Tablet and Telephone.